# How to disable strange screen dimming for certain windows in Gnome

Tags: gnome, screen

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. When I open

- "Show Applications" form from the main menu
- empty window in Firefox
- mc or mutt in console

the screen becomes dimmed. Probably, it is some effect in Gnome.

I don't know for what purpose it was created, but it is disgusting and it irritates me a lot. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was neither Gnome, nor Ubuntu. It was Philips monitor, that had a feature "Smart contrast" I disabled it and it ended the torture.